# Join Attribute Table with multiple owners with only one Parcel

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, parcel, qgis-3

I have a problem in QGIS. I have an attribute table (no geographical information), which contains owners of parcels and an ID for every row.

Then I have a shapefile, which contains polygons and an attribute table which contains an ID (Fits with the owner information).

If I want to join these two parts, QGIS joins only one owner per parcel, even if there are 5.

How can I manage it, that finally there is a row in the attribute table of the shapefile, containing all owners and not only one?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few concepts you have to know.

A **join** is a 1-to-1-relation:  one parcel with one owner.  If you do a join in QGIS then it will take the first corresponding owner and join it to the parcel

A **relation** is normally defined as 1 to many.  This is your case.  Here you have to define the relation through project > projectproperties > relations.  Here you can set the relation-definitions.  When you open the features dialogue, you will see every connected owner in an embedded table.

If you want to only have 1 row and all the owners in 1 field, you can use SQL or QGIS-expressions.

**SQL**

suppose you have following layers:

parcels:

[image]

owners:

[image]

Go to DB-manager > virtual layers > qgis layers.  Open an sql-window and execute:

```
select parcel.*, group_concat(owner) as owners from parcel
left join owners on parcel.id = owners.parcel_id
group by owners.parcel_id
```

Load the results as a new layer